# 'NSMutableSet' is not implicitly convertible to 'Set<NSObject>'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-plot

I am using coreplot to plot graph in my app.
When i try to assign X-Axis label or major tick location it is throwing error though `NSMutableSet` is converted to Set of NSObject Type.
Here is how i have written my code:

```
xAxis.axisLabels = xAxisLabels as Set<NSObject>
xAxis.majorTickLocations = xMajorTickLocations as Set<NSObject>
```

The error thrown is as follows

```
'NSMutableSet' is not implicitly convertible to 'Set<NSObject>'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert
```

Comment: Have you tried what the compiler suggested?

Comment: yes.. compiler just asked me to add `as Set<NSObject>` again. So when i used the compiler suggestion it just became `xAxis.axisLabels = xAxisLabels as Set<NSObject> as Set<NSObject>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use native Swift types rather than Foundation collections when possible. This eliminates the need for casting.

```
var xAxisLabels = Set<CPTAxisLabel>()
var xMajorTickLocations = Set<NSNumber>()
```